# Sequential minimization of a function.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose there is a decreasing function $f(x)$ that is lower bounded. In each step we strictly reduce the function such that $f(x_i)>f(x_{i+1})$. Then can we say that after finite number of steps we always achieve the minimum? Or are there sequences of $x_i,x_{i+1},\dots$ which will go forever without reaching the minimum even if  $f(x_i)>f(x_{i+1})$?

If so what are sufficient conditions to guarantee the minimum is achieved in finite steps?

Comment: What does $1/n$ do? What if the function is constant on some interval $[a, \infty[$?

Comment: But we can select $x_i$ only such that $f(x_i)>f(x_{i+1})$. So we can't select two $x_i$s in a region where the function is constant.

Comment: I omitted the strict inequality. Sorry. You can't attain the minimum with your sequence (if you do, you reach a contradiction with the next term of the sequence).

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more? Why can't last $x_n$ be such that $f(x_n)$ is the minimum?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have $f$ a decreasing function bounded below by $c \in \mathbb R$.

If $f$ is strictly decreasing, then, on the one hand, for any sequence $(x_n)$ that is such that $\forall n \in \mathbb N, f(x_i)>f(x_{i+1})$, $(x_n)$ must be strictly increasing .

On the other hand, suppose that for a given $j \in \mathbb N$, $f(x_j)=c$. Then by assumption, $f(x_{j+1}) < c$. This contradicts the boundedness of $f$.

The sequence $1/n$ associated with the function $1/x$ has the required properties, and $f(1/n)$ never attains the (best) lower bound $0$.